# How to create a route to show Laravel API relationships?

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-5, eloquent

I am able to use Tinker to see relationship between product and reviews. Results are returned.

```
php artisan tinker
>> App\Model\Product::find(1)->reviews
```

How do I create a route and a controller to show this relationship because the show method is already being used to show by ID.  Do I use the product controller or the reviews controller? Can I show both ways reviews by product and products by reviews?

UPDATED

Here is my products data

```
Data: [
{
productName: "television",
price: null,
id: 1
},
```

Here is my reviews data

```
data: [
{
id: 2,
customerId: "4",
booktitle: null,
description: null,
likes: null,
customer: null,
body: null,
star: null,
productId: "1"
},
```

Here is my review model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Review extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $table = 'REVIEWS';

    protected $fillable = [
    'booktitle', 'description', 'updated_at', 'created_at',
    ];

/*  public function customer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Customers::class); 
    }*/

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class); 
    }

}
```

I know I don't have a review field in the product table.

This route http://localhost:8000/api/v1/reviews/2/products is trying to run a query select * from [PRODUCTS] where [PRODUCTS].[review_id] = 2 but review_id is not a column name in my table so I don't know where this is being picked up from.

This route http://localhost:8000/api/v1/products/2/reviews is returning a 200 ok but is a blank screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create two route if you want to get both, reviews by product and product by review.

**routes**

```
Route::get('/product/{id}/reviews', 'ProductController@getReviews');
Route::get('/review/{id}/product', 'ReviewController@getProduct');
```

**ProductController**

```
public function getReviews(Request $request, $id){
  return App\Model\Product::findOrFail($id)->reviews;
}
```

**ReviewController**

```
public function getReviews(Request $request, $id){
  // considering you have set up relationship and Model: App\Model\Review
  return App\Model\Review::findOrFail($id)->product;
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I thought I was limited to the index, store etc. methods. I have followed your instructions but am still stuck. Are you able to help?

Comment: Thank you.  After following the instructions iit appeared to be looking for a controller that is referenced in my web.php file.  It also seemed to be looking for \http\controller\app\model\review instead of app\model\review. I'm going to create a new project and try again to see if that will fix the problem.

Comment: I have restructured my code into a new project but still not able to get it to work.  I have edited my question above.

Comment: Looks like you have your product and review modelis in `App\` namespace. Just change above classes in controller with `App\Review` and `App\Product` (instead of `App\Models\...` )